# Select part of row values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset like this:

```
S.No  Param  1st  2nd  3rd  4th....15th
1     a      65   45   86   52 ....
2     b      62   666  8    785....
```

I want to plot freq for each param and the columns after that till 15th

I have taken the set of columns and extracted them from S.No and Param. Now the dataset looks like this

```
1st  2nd  3rd  4th....15th
65   45   86   52 ....
62   666  8    785....
```

How to plot for each param and each row with the 1st, 2nd, 3rd... as x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) in the plot , something like:

Using the original data:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x="Params",y='value' ,hue="value", data=pd.melt(df,id_vars='Params'))
```

[image]

where output of `print(pd.melt(df,id_vars='Params'))` is:

```
  Params variable  value
0      a      1st     65
1      b      1st     62
2      a      2nd     45
3      b      2nd    666
4      a      3rd     86
5      b      3rd      8
```